# Select only values with lower hierarchy

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a config table CONFIG_STUFF:

```
Table_name: varchar
Field_name: varchar
Parent_name: varchar
```

The overlying system has a number of fields that are hierarchical in nature, fully customisable.

Example:

```
Table_Name  Field_Name  Parent_Name
Tab1        CostCenter  Division
Tab2        Division    null
Tab3        Division    null
Tab4        Team        CostCenter
```

What I need to do is determine the level of a given field within this hierarchy, and then select the table_name and field_name of it and everything below it, while excluding those above

For example, for 'CostCenter', I would return:

```
Table_Name  Field_Name
Tab1        CostCenter
Tab4        Team
```

and for 'Division', I would return:

```
Table_Name  Field_Name  
Tab1        CostCenter  
Tab2        Division    
Tab3        Division    
Tab4        Team
```

So far, I have tried to use `connect by`, but can't get it to work how I want.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is the table_name field relevant to the relationship; it doesn't seem so, but there are two possible parents for `CostCenter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need to know the level of your starting point. You can use the `start with` clause to figure out everything below it:

```
-- cte for your sample data
with config_stuff (table_name, field_name, parent_name) as (
  select 'Tab1', 'CostCenter', 'Division' from dual
  union all select 'Tab2', 'Division', null from dual
  union all select 'Tab3', 'Division', null from dual
  union all select 'Tab4', 'Team', 'CostCenter' from dual
)
-- actual query
select table_name, field_name
from config_stuff
start with field_name = 'CostCenter'
connect by parent_name = prior field_name;

TABLE_NAME FIELD_NAME
---------- ----------
Tab1       CostCenter
Tab4       Team
```

But your hierarchy isn't unique, so the same thing for division gets duplicates, as `CostCenter` has two parent rows with `Division`.

```
select table_name, field_name
from config_stuff
start with field_name = 'Division'
connect by parent_name = prior field_name;

TABLE_NAME FIELD_NAME
---------- ----------
Tab2       Division  
Tab1       CostCenter
Tab4       Team      
Tab3       Division  
Tab1       CostCenter
Tab4       Team
```

You can add a `distinct` to get rid of the duplicates of course:

```
select distinct table_name, field_name
from config_stuff
start with field_name = 'Division'
connect by parent_name = prior field_name;

TABLE_NAME FIELD_NAME
---------- ----------
Tab4       Team      
Tab2       Division  
Tab3       Division  
Tab1       CostCenter
```

but that can indicate a data issue, and if this is fully customisable then you could potentially end up with loops (cycles).

Comment: Thanks, `start with` is new to me. Works a treat. Loops should not be possible unless someone messed up.